# Cannot launch SQL Developer 4.0.1

Tags: java, java-7, oracle-sqldeveloper

Brand new machine, new install of SQL Developer (x64 w/out JRE), when I try to launch `sqldeveloper.exe`, it gets stuck at about 10%.

[image: screenshot of Oracle SQL Developer loading stuck at about 10%]

What logs, if any, should I be looking at for errors?

Version info:

- SQL Developer 4.0.1
- JDK 1.7.0_55
- Windows 7 Professional x64

I ran `sqldeveloper64.exe`, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> when the launcher started hanging. This is the output:

```
2014-04-17 10:26:08 Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
(24.55-b03 mixed mode):

"Flushing caches" prio=2 tid=0x000000000cf4b000 nid=0x2408 in Object.wait() [0x00000000104af000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000ce69ea98> (a org.netbeans.Stamps$Worker)
        at org.netbeans.Stamps$Worker.run(Stamps.java:824)
        - locked <0x00000000ce69ea98> (a org.netbeans.Stamps$Worker)

"Thread-3" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000cf4a000 nid=0x1d60 in Object.wait() [0x000000000e21f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000f2053220> (a java.util.LinkedList)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences$EventDispatchThread.run(AbstractPreferences.java:1476)
        - locked <0x00000000f2053220> (a java.util.LinkedList)

"Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000cf49800 nid=0x2744 in Object.wait() [0x000000000e07f000]   
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000f4043468> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
        - locked <0x00000000f4043468> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

"State Saver" prio=6 tid=0x000000000cf48800 nid=0x265c in Object.wait() [0x000000000df0f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000f3c73208> (a org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.SystemState)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage$StateSaver.run(BaseStorage.java:1292)
        - locked <0x00000000f3c73208> (a org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.SystemState)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Framework Active Thread" prio=6 tid=0x000000000cf48000 nid=0x2014 in Object.wait() [0x000000000ddbf000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000f3c704a8> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.run(Framework.java:1863)
        - locked <0x00000000f3c704a8> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Inactive RequestProcessor thread [Was:Folderrecognizer/org.openide.loaders.FolderList$ListTask]" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000cd80000 nid=0x25d8 in Object.wait() [0x000000000dcbf000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000f3f6d648> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1989)
        - locked <0x00000000f3f6d648> (a java.lang.Object)

"RequestProcessor queue manager" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000cb5d800 nid=0x2720  in Object.wait() [0x000000000dbbf000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000ce846c20> (a java.lang.Class for org.openide.uti l.RequestProcessor$TickTac)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$TickTac.obtainFirst(RequestProcessor.java:2267)
        - locked <0x00000000ce846c20> (a java.lang.Class for org.openide.util.Re questProcessor$TickTac)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$TickTac.run(RequestProcessor.java:2243)

"Inactive RequestProcessor thread [Was:NbStatusDisplayer/org.netbeans.core.NbStatusDisplayer$MessageImpl]" daemon prio=2 tid=0x000000000cc08000 nid=0x27dc in Object.wait() [0x000000000d9bf000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000f3de60d8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1989)
        - locked <0x00000000f3de60d8> (a java.lang.Object)

"CLI Requests Server" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000cb61000 nid=0x1c3c runnable [0x000000000d8bf000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
        - locked <0x00000000f40426e8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler$Server.run(CLIHandler.java:1100)

"Active Reference Queue Daemon" daemon prio=2 tid=0x000000000cb8a800 nid=0x23bc in Object.wait() [0x000000000d5cf000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000f3c4a298> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
        - locked <0x00000000f3c4a298> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at org.openide.util.lookup.implspi.ActiveQueue$Daemon.run(ActiveQueue.java:180)
        - locked <0x00000000f3c4a298> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)

"TimerQueue" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000009ebf800 nid=0x1f64 waiting on condition [0x000000000d3cf000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000f3f6df90> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
        at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:220)
        at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(TimerQueue.java:171)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x0000000009dc7800 nid=0xe14 waiting on condition [0x000000000baef000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000f3f79a30> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(EventQueue.java:543)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

"AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000009dc6800 nid=0x26dc runnable [0x000000000b80f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:307)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"AWT-Shutdown" prio=6 tid=0x0000000009dc3800 nid=0x11dc in Object.wait() [0x000000000b70f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000f3f74aa0> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(AWTAutoShutdown.java:296)
        - locked <0x00000000f3f74aa0> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000009dc3000 nid=0x1ecc in Object.wait() [0x000000000b60f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000f3efed88> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
        - locked <0x00000000f3efed88> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
        at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:145)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000008a9e000 nid=0x1404 runnable [0x000 0000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000008a9d800 nid=0x1814 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000008a96800 nid=0x128c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000008a95000 nid=0x2564 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000008a94800 nid=0x24c4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x000000000234b000 nid=0x27a0 in Object.wait() [0x000000000ae4f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000ce721080> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
        - locked <0x00000000ce721080> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000008a80000 nid=0x276c in Object.wait() [0x000000000ad4f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000ce6c1ad8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
        - locked <0x00000000ce6c1ad8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022bb800 nid=0x1f04 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000008a7c000 nid=0x27ec runnable "GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022d1000 nid=0x24d4 runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022d3800 nid=0x1934 runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022d5000 nid=0x1d1c runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022d7000 nid=0x223c runnable

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022da000 nid=0x260c runnable

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022db800 nid=0x1544 runnable

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022dd000 nid=0x1898 runnable

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022de000 nid=0x1004 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000009c64000 nid=0xc4c waiting on condition

JNI global references: 669

Heap
  PSYoungGen      total 72704K, used 63022K [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000f4100000,0x0000000100000000)
    eden space 67584K, 85% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000f2d93858,0x00000000f3700000)
    from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000f3c00000,0x00000000f40f8198,0x00000000f4100000)
    to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000f3700000,0x00000000f3700000,0x00000000f3c00000)
  ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 15371K [0x00000000ce000000,0x00000000d3580000,0x00000000ef500000)
    object space 87552K, 17% used [0x00000000ce000000,0x00000000cef02c80,0x00000000d3580000)
  PSPermGen       total 23040K, used 22672K [0x00000000be000000,0x00000000bf680000,0x00000000ce000000)
    object space 23040K, 98% used [0x00000000be000000,0x00000000bf624068,0x00000000bf680000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know why, but installing to a different directory fixed the problem. It was originally installed in `c:\oracle\sqldeveloper` (as it was in my previous environment when everything was working happily), and I moved it to `c:\sqldeveloper`, now everything is working. I also cleared out the AppData folders (`\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer` and `\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper`), but I had done that countless times prior to relocating the installation during troubleshooting. I should also note I double and triple checked security settings on the original install directory and my user had full control.

Answer (score 1):

**Same problem - solved by moving to different directory...** More by mistake I tried to run datamodeler from destination, which included "!" in its path (like "c:\!!! - datamodeler"). Not possible. After moving anywhere without "!" in path it started to work OK.

- Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
- Oracle Data Modeler 4.5.1.
- Oracle Data Modeler 4.2 Beta - the same situation...

No error, no log... just crash after 1.5cm progressbar on splashscreen...
2 Hours of life gone. Hope it helps somebody...

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I have windows 10, 64x.
What i have done want to set up the jdk on env variables, set the java path on config file but nothing.
Moving the sqldeveloper to C:/ from Program Files and deleting  \AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer and \AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by removing the content of following two folders:

```
1. C:\Users\windows_user_name\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\SqlHistory
2. C:\Users\windows_user_name\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\systemxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem - solved by moving to different directory... More by 
mistake I tried to run datamodeler from destination, which included "!" in its path (like "c:!!! - datamodeler"). Not possible. After moving anywhere without "!" in path it started to work OK.

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393] Oracle Data Modeler 4.5.1.
>   Oracle Data Modeler 4.2 Beta - the same situation... No error, no
>   log... just crash after 1.5cm progressbar on splashscreen... 2 Hours
>   of life gone. Hope it helps somebody...

It helps me.