# SQL Developer crashes randomly every time

Tags: java, jvm, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have searched for hours but I have no idea how to solve this issue.

```
My SQL Developer (Version 4.1.5) crashes every time I execute it.     
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

I get the following error:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000, pid=4728, tid=0x00001638

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  0x00000000

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x373ba000):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=5688, stack(0x38530000,0x38630000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x3862e8c0, EBX=0x0064e100, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x00000140
ESP=0x3862e8a8, EBP=0x3862ea28, ESI=0x74c21222, EDI=0x0064e174
EIP=0x00000000, EFLAGS=0x00010212

Top of Stack: (sp=0x3862e8a8)
0x3862e8a8:   679d38e7 3862e8c0 0064e174 74c21222
0x3862e8b8:   0064e168 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x3862e8c8:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x3862e8d8:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x3862e8e8:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x3862e8f8:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x3862e908:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x3862e918:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000)
0xffffffe0:   


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x3862e8c0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x373ba000
EBX=0x0064e100 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000140 is an unknown value
ESP=0x3862e8a8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x373ba000
EBP=0x3862ea28 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x373ba000
ESI=0x74c21222 is an unknown value
EDI=0x0064e174 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x38530000,0x38630000],  sp=0x3862e8a8,  free space=1018k
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.getMaxConfigsImpl(I)I+0
j  sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.getMaxConfigs(I)I+10
j  sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.getConfigurations()[Ljava/awt/GraphicsConfiguration;+69
j  javax.swing.ToolTipManager.getDrawingGC(Ljava/awt/Point;)Ljava/awt/GraphicsConfiguration;+36
j  javax.swing.ToolTipManager.showTipWindow()V+115
j  javax.swing.ToolTipManager$insideTimerAction.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+113
J 4687 C1 javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V (46 bytes) @ 0x02e9266c [0x02e925a0+0xcc]
J 4999 C1 javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run()V (95 bytes) @ 0x02d43d7c [0x02d43a10+0x36c]
J 3573 C1 java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V (69 bytes) @ 0x02d2d31c [0x02d2d230+0xec]
J 4693 C1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (149 bytes) @ 0x02b69d50 [0x02b69890+0x4c0]
J 3569 C1 java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void; (60 bytes) @ 0x02d2df1c [0x02d2dec0+0x5c]
J 3568 C1 java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (5 bytes) @ 0x02d2e2e0 [0x02d2e2c0+0x20]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 1437  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x02d17147 [0x02d170e0+0x67]
J 4691 C1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (80 bytes) @ 0x02b6a7f8 [0x02b6a5f0+0x208]
J 3791 C1 oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (123 bytes) @ 0x02d7d0d0 [0x02d7cee0+0x1f0]
J 3789 C1 oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (10 bytes) @ 0x02d7dc4c [0x02d7dc10+0x3c]
J 1863 C1 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V (295 bytes) @ 0x02db4610 [0x02db3f80+0x690]
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------


Heap:
 def new generation   total 56384K, used 53430K [0x04c00000, 0x08920000, 0x156a0000)
  eden space 50176K,  99% used [0x04c00000, 0x07cfc990, 0x07d00000)
  from space 6208K,  52% used [0x07d00000, 0x080311c8, 0x08310000)
  to   space 6208K,   0% used [0x08310000, 0x08310000, 0x08920000)
 tenured generation   total 125080K, used 84622K [0x156a0000, 0x1d0c6000, 0x36c00000)
   the space 125080K,  67% used [0x156a0000, 0x1a943a00, 0x1a943a00, 0x1d0c6000)
 Metaspace       used 52214K, capacity 54806K, committed 54912K, reserved 55680K

Card table byte_map: [0x04a50000,0x04bf0000] byte_map_base: 0x04a2a000

Polling page: 0x00420000

CodeCache: size=32768Kb used=4784Kb max_used=4977Kb free=27983Kb
 bounds [0x02a50000, 0x02f40000, 0x04a50000]
 total_blobs=2641 nmethods=2286 adapters=284
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 171.962 Thread 0x373a7000 5540             sun.swing.MenuItemLayoutHelper$RectSize::access$300 (5 bytes)
Event: 171.962 Thread 0x373a7000 nmethod 5540 0x02d6e188 code [0x02d6e280, 0x02d6e2f0]
Event: 171.967 Thread 0x373a7000 5541             sun.swing.MenuItemLayoutHelper::max (40 bytes)
Event: 171.967 Thread 0x373a7000 nmethod 5541 0x02d71f08 code [0x02d72000, 0x02d720a0]
Event: 171.975 Thread 0x373a7000 5542             javax.swing.GrayFilter::filterRGB (136 bytes)
Event: 171.975 Thread 0x373a7000 nmethod 5542 0x02caaf88 code [0x02cab0c0, 0x02cab280]
Event: 171.976 Thread 0x373a7000 5543             sun.java2d.SurfaceData::canRenderParallelograms (137 bytes)
Event: 171.977 Thread 0x373a7000 nmethod 5543 0x02d6d9c8 code [0x02d6daf0, 0x02d6dce8]
Event: 171.984 Thread 0x373a7000 5544   !         sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D::fillRect (74 bytes)
Event: 171.985 Thread 0x373a7000 nmethod 5544 0x02d36e08 code [0x02d36f30, 0x02d37144]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 166.059 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=32 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 56384K, used 51969K [0x04c00000, 0x08920000, 0x156a0000)
  eden space 50176K, 100% used [0x04c00000, 0x07d00000, 0x07d00000)
  from space 6208K,  28% used [0x08310000, 0x084d04d0, 0x08920000)
  to   space 6208K,   0% used [0x07d00000, 0x07d00000, 0x08310000)
 tenured generation   total 125080K, used 82025K [0x156a0000, 0x1d0c6000, 0x36c00000)
   the space 125080K,  65% used [0x156a0000, 0x1a6ba6e8, 0x1a6ba800, 0x1d0c6000)
 Metaspace       used 48450K, capacity 50901K, committed 51072K, reserved 51584K
Event: 166.063 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=33 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 56384K, used 2139K [0x04c00000, 0x08920000, 0x156a0000)
  eden space 50176K,   0% used [0x04c00000, 0x04c00000, 0x07d00000)
  from space 6208K,  34% used [0x07d00000, 0x07f16f80, 0x08310000)
  to   space 6208K,   0% used [0x08310000, 0x08310000, 0x08920000)
 tenured generation   total 125080K, used 82025K [0x156a0000, 0x1d0c6000, 0x36c00000)
   the space 125080K,  65% used [0x156a0000, 0x1a6ba6e8, 0x1a6ba800, 0x1d0c6000)
 Metaspace       used 48450K, capacity 50901K, committed 51072K, reserved 51584K
}
```

0x08310000)
      to   space 6208K,   0% used [0x08310000, 0x08310000, 0x08920000)
     tenured generation   total 125080K, used 83134K [0x156a0000, 0x1d0c6000, 0x36c00000)
       the space 125080K,  66% used [0x156a0000, 0x1a7cf948, 0x1a7cfa00, 0x1d0c6000)
     Metaspace       used 49663K, capacity 52126K, committed 52224K, reserved 52608K

```
Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 168.830 Thread 0x373ba000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x07900100) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 168.853 Thread 0x373ba000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x07915b58) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 168.855 Thread 0x373ba000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x07925af0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 168.858 Thread 0x373ba000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x079527a0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 170.223 Thread 0x373ba000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x059a5128) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 170.539 Thread 0x373ba000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x06523fa0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 170.543 Thread 0x373ba000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x065e2f38) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 170.731 Thread 0x3fa6ac00 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x06969a00) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 170.731 Thread 0x3fa6ac00 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x06969c80) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 170.731 Thread 0x3fa6ac00 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x06969ed0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]

Events (10 events):
Event: 171.957 Thread 0x373a7000 flushing nmethod 0x02d72ac8
Event: 171.959 Thread 0x373a7000 flushing nmethod 0x02ed1748
Event: 171.959 Thread 0x373a7000 flushing nmethod 0x02ed1b48
Event: 171.959 Thread 0x373a7000 flushing nmethod 0x02ed1d48
Event: 171.959 Thread 0x373a7000 flushing nmethod 0x02ed1fc8
Event: 171.975 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 171.976 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 171.986 Thread 0x373a7000 flushing nmethod 0x02ceb148
Event: 171.986 Thread 0x373a7000 flushing nmethod 0x02d2eb88
Event: 171.986 Thread 0x373a7000 flushing nmethod 0x02d2f888


Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00417000     C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper.exe
0x76fa0000 - 0x77120000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x74c10000 - 0x74d20000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x75ed0000 - 0x75f17000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x755e0000 - 0x756e0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x75970000 - 0x75a00000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x751a0000 - 0x751aa000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x74900000 - 0x7499d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x75c80000 - 0x75d2c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x75760000 - 0x75801000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x75d30000 - 0x75d49000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x75090000 - 0x75180000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x74890000 - 0x748f0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x74880000 - 0x7488c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x75580000 - 0x755e0000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x758a0000 - 0x7596d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x00500000 - 0x00525000     C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\ide\bin\launcher.dll
0x75f20000 - 0x76b6c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x75520000 - 0x75577000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x75390000 - 0x754ed000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x72a50000 - 0x72a59000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x72510000 - 0x72590000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x74090000 - 0x740a3000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x6fec0000 - 0x6ff7f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x6faf0000 - 0x6febc000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x73d60000 - 0x73d67000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x75350000 - 0x75385000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x75080000 - 0x75086000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x74370000 - 0x743a2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x74ad0000 - 0x74ad5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x73d50000 - 0x73d5c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x734e0000 - 0x73501000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java.dll
0x73090000 - 0x730a3000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x756e0000 - 0x756eb000     C:\Windows\syswow64\profapi.dll
0x6ffe0000 - 0x70125000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x749a0000 - 0x74a31000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x73990000 - 0x73a14000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18837_none_ec86b8d6858ec0bc\COMCTL32.dll
0x72480000 - 0x724b9000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x72460000 - 0x72476000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\net.dll
0x70350000 - 0x7038c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x72450000 - 0x72456000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x6ffd0000 - 0x6ffdf000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x6fa10000 - 0x6fa42000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\t2k.dll
0x6f9e0000 - 0x6fa04000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\dcpr.dll
0x72430000 - 0x72447000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x723f0000 - 0x7242b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x75740000 - 0x75757000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USERENV.dll
0x72ad0000 - 0x72aec000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x72ac0000 - 0x72ac7000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x73f40000 - 0x73f52000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x73f30000 - 0x73f3d000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x6de50000 - 0x6de60000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x6de40000 - 0x6de50000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x6de20000 - 0x6de32000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x6faa0000 - 0x6fae4000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x6de10000 - 0x6de18000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x6dde0000 - 0x6de01000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x6ddd0000 - 0x6dddd000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x6dda0000 - 0x6ddc7000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x70340000 - 0x70345000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x6dd80000 - 0x6dd86000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x6dd40000 - 0x6dd78000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x02370000 - 0x0238b000     C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\idenative.dll
0x69120000 - 0x6912a000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\management.dll
0x72c80000 - 0x72ca0000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\sunec.dll
0x74fe0000 - 0x75063000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x72840000 - 0x729de000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_41e855142bd5705d\comctl32.dll
0x72b40000 - 0x72c71000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x70950000 - 0x7099c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x72b00000 - 0x72b36000     C:\Users\MongoMongo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SkyDrive\17.0.4035.0328\SkyDriveShell.dll
0x68f60000 - 0x68fe5000     C:\Users\MongoMongo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SkyDrive\17.0.4035.0328\MSVCP110.dll
0x67b30000 - 0x67c02000     C:\Users\MongoMongo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SkyDrive\17.0.4035.0328\MSVCR110.dll
0x67aa0000 - 0x67b27000     C:\Users\MongoMongo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SkyDrive\17.0.4035.0328\Telemetry.dll
0x740f0000 - 0x740fa000     C:\Users\MongoMongo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SkyDrive\17.0.4035.0328\logging.dll
0x690c0000 - 0x69112000     C:\Windows\system32\faultrep.dll
0x6ce90000 - 0x6cea5000     C:\Windows\system32\Cabinet.dll
0x729e0000 - 0x72a38000     C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x725a0000 - 0x725f0000     C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll
0x73d70000 - 0x73d9f000     C:\Windows\system32\XmlLite.dll
0x74d20000 - 0x74f7c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WININET.dll
0x75890000 - 0x75894000     C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll
0x75070000 - 0x75074000     C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll
0x75500000 - 0x75504000     C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll
0x754f0000 - 0x754f3000     C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll
0x75c40000 - 0x75c43000     C:\Windows\syswow64\normaliz.DLL
0x75a00000 - 0x75c34000     C:\Windows\syswow64\iertutil.dll
0x748f0000 - 0x748f5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll
0x67740000 - 0x678e9000     C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\GROOVEEX.DLL
0x67a30000 - 0x67a99000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP100.dll
0x6ce60000 - 0x6ce86000     C:\Windows\system32\ATL100.DLL
0x725f0000 - 0x72836000     C:\Windows\system32\msi.dll
0x669b0000 - 0x6723d000     C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\1031\GrooveIntlResource.dll
0x679f0000 - 0x67a21000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorShell.dll
0x751b0000 - 0x7534d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x75c50000 - 0x75c77000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x75180000 - 0x75192000     C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x73790000 - 0x73885000     C:\Windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll
0x67910000 - 0x67980000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x72a70000 - 0x72a89000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x724f0000 - 0x724fb000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x72af0000 - 0x72afa000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x6dfb0000 - 0x6dfb6000     C:\Windows\system32\IconCodecService.dll
0x66920000 - 0x669ae000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\mlib_image.dll
0x69130000 - 0x69139000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x74ae0000 - 0x74c01000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
0x76f70000 - 0x76f7c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
0x65440000 - 0x65508000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.DLL
0x68f30000 - 0x68f52000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x65350000 - 0x65437000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x690b0000 - 0x690b6000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x679d0000 - 0x679e5000     C:\Windows\system32\atiglpxx.dll
0x722e0000 - 0x723cb000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\lib\tools.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\lib\dt.jar -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dnetbeans.home=/Users/MongoMongo/Desktop/Schule/5klasse/DBI - REL/sqldeveloper/netbeans/platform/ -Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -Dexcluded.modules=org.eclipse.osgi -Dide.cluster.dirs=/Users/MongoMongo/Desktop/Schule/5klasse/DBI - REL/sqldeveloper/netbeans/fcpbridge/:/Users/MongoMongo/Desktop/Schule/5klasse/DBI - REL/sqldeveloper/netbeans/ide/:/Users/MongoMongo/Desktop/Schule/5klasse/DBI - REL/sqldeveloper/netbeans/../ -Xverify:none -Doracle.ide.extension.HooksProcessingMode=LAZY -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:bundles.info -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=1 -Dosgi.configuration.cascaded=false -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=* -Dosgi.parentClassloader=app -Dosgi.locking=none -Dosgi.contextClassLoaderParent=app -Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/MongoMongo/Desktop/Schule/5klasse/DBI - REL/sqldeveloper/rdbms/jlib/ojdi.jar -Dosgi.classloader.type=parallel -Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=500 -Dide.feedback-server=ide.us.oracle.com -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=oracle.ide.xml.switchable.SwitchableTransformerFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.util.XMLEventAllocator=oracle.ideimpl.xml.stream.XMLEventAllocatorImpl -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations=bug -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations.exceptionsfile=/Users/MongoMongo/Desktop/Schule/5klasse/DBI - REL/sqldeveloper/ide/bin/swing-thread-violations.conf -Xms128M -Xmx800M -Doracle.ide.IdeFrameworkCommandLineOptions=-clean,-console,-debugmode,-migrate,-migrate:,-nomigrate,-nonag,-nondebugmode,-noreopen,-nosplash,-role:,-su -Dide.update.usage.servers=http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/sqldeveloper/usage.xml -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false -Dwindows.shell.font.languages= -Doracle.ide.startup.features=sqldeveloper -Doracle.ide.osgi.boot.api.OJStartupHook=oracle.dbtools.raptor.startup.HomeSupport -Doracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false -Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false -Doracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn=true -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true -Dorg.netbeans.CLIHandler.server=false -Dide.AssertTracingDisabled=true -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.conf -Dsqldev.debug=false -Dsqldev.onsd=true -Dide.startingArg0=C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper.exe -Dide.launcherProcessId=4728 -Dide.config_pathname=C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf -Dide.startingcwd=C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper -Duser.conf=C:\Users\MongoMongo\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\4.1.5\product.conf -Dtool.user.conf=C:\Users\MongoMongo\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\4.1.5\sqldeveloper.conf -Dide.shell.enableFileTypeAssociation=C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper.exe -Dide.pref.dir.base=C:\Users\MongoMongo\AppData\Roaming -Dide.work.dir.base=C:\Users\MongoMongo\Documents 
java_command: oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\ide-boot.jar;C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\netbeans\platform\lib\boot.jar;C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-util-ui.jar;C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-util.jar;C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-util-lookup.jar;C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-modules.jar;C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\fcpboot.jar;C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\xml-factory.jar;C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar;C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\stax2-api-3.1.1.jar;C:\Users\MongoMongo\Desktop\Schule\5klasse\DBI - REL\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\lib\oracle.sqldeveloper.homesupport.jar
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_1\jre\1.4.2\bin\client;C:\oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\ProgramData\Lenovo\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Users\MongoMongo\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
USERNAME=MongoMongo
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23569)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 61 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 8116408k(5861944k free), swap 16230956k(13848140k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.101-b13) for windows-x86 JRE (1.8.0_101-b13), built on Jun 22 2016 00:45:44 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Thu Nov 17 10:21:45 2016
elapsed time: 172 seconds (0d 0h 2m 52s)
```

Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23205663/2814308) a similar problem (JVM crash from SQL developer) got solved by reinstalling to a different folder. It might even be that the folder doesn't matter and just uninstalling and reinstalling does the trick. Consider trying something like that or adding the information about that if you already tried.

Comment: In my case it would crash on startup - I moved the folder in another directory (the original one contained a `!`) and it started fine. Go figure...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The crash has happened inside `atiglpxx.dll`, which seems to be a part of graphics driver.

Try one or more of the following options:

- Add `-Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true` JVM argument;
- Remove `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true` and `-Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false` arguments;
- Install different graphics driver.

Comment: Removing -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false and adding -Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true worked

Comment: wish I could give a 100 upvotes for this answer, you saved me a few hours

Comment: -Dsun.java2d.d3d=true worked for me, as noted here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095662

Comment: These changes should be applied to the `ide/bin/jdk.conf` file. Adding just the first setting resolved my issue with Oracle SQL Developer (v18.x-19.2) crashing randomly when working on a remote computer via Remote Desktop Connection.